# Getting R error while including dependencies in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, material-design

Am new in android studio and i was trying to test some material design things.
and i just added some dependencies for this purpose

Here is the code that causing R error

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'

}
```

But there isn't any problem if we try to use

```
    compile 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:2.3.3'
```

or

```
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
```

The problem comes when i use these together.

Am beginner to this android studio. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

![After rebuilding its showing the this error  ] https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoToP.png

Comment: your dependencies are defining the same attr.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to Clean and and then Rebuild your project in the Build menu. If that does not work, try using this lines insted:

```
 compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
 compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

Comment: getting tat error when i use 3 of them not when adding 
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
 compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0' only

Comment: I saw your edit. I think that the libraries are both triyng to set the "rippleColor" value at the same time, therefore causing some kind problema between both.

Comment: I would suggest going to the file named above the error message (double click) and in the file deleting the line where it says "rippleColor".

Comment: but i cant edit tat. its a generated file. Any options?

Comment: I'm talking about the file in the third line of your screenshot. Are you sure that you can't edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, update your IDE, then rebuild the project.

From the error shown, it seems that you are writting in res\values\values twice. And giving 2 different values to the same Attribute.

As a quick fix, you may compile with just `'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'` and `com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'`, save that values.xml someone where else, then compile the rest, and manually merge the files.
If the source of those materials are beyond your control, you may have issues importing the content, if not try renaming that attribute in one of the packages.

As a final resort, manually merge content in the folder, then import the project as a new one. i have had issues with Android Studio, and those tend to be solved with updates to the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The rippleColor conflict with other libraries is a known issue that was reported in [[1]](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/274), [[2]](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/277) and [[3]](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/289)

You can try to use another library from here:

- [Carbon](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon)
- [rey5137/material](https://github.com/rey5137/material)
- [GreenMatter](https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter)